Is a string safe to display if the characters <>; are filtered out?
I have a Laravel app and because I need to add links and html entities to a string I'm using {!! $text !!} instead of {{ $text }} when displaying it in the view.
The only part of $text from the user is message. for example:
Current value is 35 &#9730; which you can check <a href="here">here</a> and you also have a message: {short message from someone}

My question is, if I validate the input for that message and don't allow 3 characters (< > ;) is that message considered safe to display in view without escaping?

Probably. But why are you mixing the two together in the first place; why is the user-entered message part of this $text already - and not still contained in a variable of its own, which could then easily get different treatment applied?

@C3roe Because I have a "template" for these messages that I then use str_replace to put in the values from database. e.g. Current value is %amount% &#9730; which you can check <a href="%link%">here</a> and you also have a message: %message% so when passed to view they are already mixed together. and it's in an array like 50 texts and each with its own template. it's just an example, bit more complicated than that and variables are stored in db as json. this way I can display the message in different languages too

Then you need to HTML-encode any user value when you interpolate it into that template.

Although this use case will likely catch most cases, there are already an abundance of dedicated tools such as html purifier which are created for this purpose and will almost certainly do a better job for this use case
